# Runtime library heap error using Crypto++ and VS2019 with MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2019, crypto++

I have to update an old MFC application to the newest MFC version "v142" compiled by Visual Studio 2019. I also updated Crypto++ to version 8.2 and followed Crypto++ advice to change [C++ Runtime Linking](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Visual_Studio#Runtime_Linking).

But still Crypto++ is using a different C++ runtime library then MFC application: When memory allocated in Crypto++ DLL is freed in the MFC application I get (on C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\atlmfc\src\mfc\afxmem.cpp:328):

> HEAP[CryptoPPHashApp.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00F00000, 0125E090 )
>   CryptoPPHashApp.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

[image: Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library Error]

I created a new dialog MFC application with VS Wizard with an input field, message box, and a button to test the problem and see if there maybe other settings problematic. But I got the same error as above, as soon the code leaves the scope of `CCryptoPPHashAppDlg::OnButtonCalculate()`.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "CryptoPPHashApp.h"
#include "CryptoPPHashAppDlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

#include <dll.h>
#include <sha.h>
#include <filters.h>
#include <hex.h>

#include <string>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

using std::string;
using namespace CryptoPP;

void CCryptoPPHashAppDlg::OnButtonCalculate()
{
    UpdateData(TRUE);

    SHA256 sha256;
    string hash{};
    auto sink = new StringSink(hash);
    auto encoder = new HexEncoder(sink);
    auto filter = new HashFilter(sha256, encoder);
    StringSource ss(m_Message, true, filter);

    m_Hash = hash.c_str();
    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

Do I have to change anything else when compiling Crypto++?

Is it possible to overload the `new`/`delete` operators which Crypto++ is using?

Any other solution to have Crypto++ as DLL in a MFC application?

Comment: *But still CryptoPP is using a different C++ runtime library then MFC application* -- That is probably because you built it that way (without being aware of it), or you're using the DLL "out of the box" without rebuilding it to use the same runtime library.

Comment: *"When memory allocated in Crypto++ DLL is freed..."* - Don't use the DLL project. It is a FIPS DLL and it is obsolete. Use the static library instead. Also see [FIPS DLL](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/FIPS_DLL) and [Wrapper DLL](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Wrapper_DLL) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Comment: It also sounds like you are mixing and matching things. Maybe you are still linking with the old version of the library instead of Crypto++ 8.2. Or maybe you are still using static linking in Crypto++ 8.2. If you put your project on GitHub I can look though some of the settings.

Comment: @jww I saw the Wrapper DLL, but I try to avoid it, because I would have to rewrite lots of code (some I would call "legacy").

Comment: @jww I don't use the FIPS DLL. I only compiled the project cryptlib with all it's configuration with option Runtime Library set to "Multi-threaded DLL".

Comment: If the statements in your question are correct, then you are using the FIPS DLL. It ***is*** the DLL produced by the Visual Studio project. I think you need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and put it on GitHub so folks can look through your library and project settings.

Comment: Something else that may help you determine if the Crypto++ Visual Studio project is in good working order... Test it using [MSBuild (Command Line)](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/MSBuild_(Command_Line)). The wiki article shows you how to test the DLL project from the command line. See the section ***Building FIPS DLL*** in the wiki article.